# Check Intersection Between Line and Rotated Rectangle

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, collision-detection

I have try many things without finding the good solution so here I am.
In my game (2D) I have to check collision with all my Object (house, garage..) which are image inside `Rotated Rectangle`, between a ray from a `Point A` to `Point B`.

I'm using Xna and there some code:

```
public void Update(List<Obstacle> Lob, DragObj Ldo)
{
    bool inter = false;
    Point A;
    Point B;

    A = new Point((int)pos.X, (int)pos.Y);
    B = new Point((int)Ldo.Position.X, (int)Ldo.Position.Y);
    for (int j = 0; j < Lob.Count(); j++) 
    {
        if (inter = interclass.LineIntersectsRect(A, B, Lob[j].Shape)) // I have this for the moment, Shape is the rectangle but not rotated )
        {
            inter = true;
            islight = false;
        }
        else
        {
            inter = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So to solve my problem, whether I find a solution to have a `rotatedRectangle` Object with a method to check collision with line. Whether totally something else, maybe only check collision between yy straight and each rotated Rectangle Axis?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Try rotating the line instead, it's just a little trig.

Comment: Rotated the line will change my 2D space organisation, doesn't it ? I'm gonna try to rotate my 2 points, but its wont be easy to implement in my current code.

Comment: but you can imagine it right? if you take both together and rotate so the rectangle is straight, you can use the regular axis-aligned rectangle function

Comment: Y I have draw it to imagine it and its ok. But It has a strange behavior. Intersection is working but not in the right place, i also tried with radians angle. I use this to rotate my point :  In 2D, you make (X,Y) from (x,y) with a rotation by angle t so:
        X = x cos t - y sin t
        Y = x sin t + y cos t

Answer (score 0):

I have solver this problem by checking intersection between my line and each side of the rotated Rectangle (I have to rotate each Line-side of the rectangle first). 
I will post the little algo soon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C# but...
There is this algorithm that can get the closest point on a line from a point.
(Note that the `closestPointOnLine` function is not my code)

```
var closestPointOnLine = function(line1, point1)
{ 
    var A1 = line1.y2 - line1.y1;
    var B1 = line1.x1 - line1.x2;

    var C1 =  A1 * line1.x1 + B1 * line1.y1;
    var C2 = -B1 * point1.x + A1 * point1.y;

    var det = A1 * A1 + B1 * B1;

    var cx = 0;
    var cy = 0;

    if(det !== 0)
    { 
        cx = ((A1 * C1 - B1 * C2) / det);
        cy = ((A1 * C2 + B1 * C1) / det);
    }else{
        cx = point1.x;
        cy = point1.y;
    }

    return {
        x : constrain(cx, Math.min(line1.x1, line1.x2), Math.max(line1.x1, line1.x2)),
        y : constrain(cy, Math.min(line1.y1, line1.y2), Math.max(line1.y1, line1.y2)),
    }; 
};
```

Before we go any further let's make it clear that:
Our line is:

```
var lineToTest = {
    x1: someNumber
    y1: someNumber,
    x2: someNumber,
    y2: someNumber
};
```

And that our rotated rectangle contains:

```
var rectToTest = {
    points: [
       {
          x : someNumber,
          y : someNumber,
       },
       {
          x : someNumber,
          y : someNumber,
       },
       {
          x : someNumber,
          y : someNumber,
       },
       {
          x : someNumber,
          y : someNumber,
       },
    ],
};
```

We then take the `lineToTest` and take it's first point and begin using the `closestPointOnLine` to get a point on a line of the `rectToTest`,
We then check if that point is touching the `lineToTest`, if it is not repeat for the other lines in the rectangle.

Now I don't actually know the code to check if a point is touching a line:
But it might go something like this:

```
function isLineTouchingPoint(line1, point)
{
     //Other code here
     //You'll have to use trigonometry for this one though

     return boolean;
}
```

Now you could convert this code into C# to get it to work.